# What are HDMI pins 13, 14 and 17 actually defined?

Tags: hdmi

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI), HDMI pins 13, 14 and 17 are:

- 13: CEC.
- 14: Reserved (HDMI 1.0–1.3a), Utility/HEAC+ (HDMI 1.4+, optional, HDMI Ethernet Channel (HEC) and Audio Return Channel (ARC)).
- 17: Ground (for DDC, CEC, ARC, and HEC).

However, in some EDA tools, its library give me this:

- 13: DDC/CECGround.
- 14: CEC.
- 17: Reserved (N.C.).

I got confused and searched more, and [this page](https://www.cableorganizer.com/learning-center/articles/hdmi-pinout.php) give me this:

- 13: CEC.
- 14: No Connect.
- 17: Ground.

This really shocks me. What are these pins really used for? Specifically, if I buy a HDMI wire in market, would these three pins being connected by a line, or hanging, or connected to the shields?

Comment: There are 5 different HDMI connectors. Make sure you're comparing like with like. The Wikipedia entry is almost certainly correct but the formal definition will come from the HDMI Forum. That middle set is more like the type C (aka Mini) pinout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and the last pinout are same and correct for the standard Type A connector which is normally used.

The middle pinout is either wrong or correct but for other than standard Type A connector.

If you buy a standard compliant cable, they are connected in standard compliant way. Cables have all wires connected, Type A and compatible connectors with pins of same name are all connected by name, not by pin number, to allow better pinouts in smaller connectors.

However, there are also cables sold that are not compliant with the standard, and don't bother to connect e.g. all ground wires, and assume that devices connect all grounds so the cable does not have to. There might be devices that assume that cables are wired correctly so the devices don't have to connect all ground wires. And then it means some cables and devices will have problems working together, because not every ground is properly connected between devices by the cables.

Answer (score 0):

I just know there are actually 3 different HDMI pin definitions for type A, type C and type D correspondingly.

I asked in the user forum of that online EDA tool, one of their staff told me they confused some of the type A HDMI connector pins with type C.